# Incorrect variable value for during average calculation for num 1 to 100

Tags: java

```
public class SumandAverage {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int sum=0;
    double average;

    int lowerBound = 1;
    int upperBound = 100;

      while(lowerBound<=upperBound) {

           sum = sum+lowerBound;
           lowerBound++;
           } 
    System.out.println("The Sum is "+sum);
    average=sum/upperBound;
    System.out.println("The average is " + average);
  }
}
```

the result i get is "The Sum is 5050 The average is 50.0"..why is my upperBound changing to 101 and resulting in incorrect average value of 50.0 instead of 50.5 when i am not even changing it at all? must be something silly, but i am not able to spot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int sum=0;
double average;

int lowerBound = 1;
int upperBound = 100;

  while(lowerBound<=upperBound) {

       sum = sum+lowerBound;
       lowerBound++;
       } 
System.out.println("The Sum is "+sum);
average=(double)sum/upperBound;            //change
System.out.println("The average is " + average);
```

ie change only `average=(double)sum/upperBound;` .In your case you are getting `int` results because `sum` and `upperBound` are int.Other option is you can also change the datatypes of these variable to get the desired output.

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/nEtBgw)

Comment: @pinkray is there a problem with my answer you unaccepted it

Comment: It must be by mistake. Totally unintentional. Your answer helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You are dividing ints, so the result is int. Divide doubles instead :

```
average=(double)sum/upperBound;
```

5050/100 = 50, since int division can only produce an int. After you assign it to a double variable, you get 50.0.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look into this. your comment has helped me fix this but i am still confused about a few things:  1. I defined the var average as double 2. and my result average =sum/upperBound resulted in 50.0 which is data type double. 3. but the expected result was 50.5. strange!

Comment: @pinkray `sum/upperBound` is a division of two ints. Therefore the result is int - 50. Once you assign that result to a double variable, it is cast to double and becomes 50.0. If you cast either `sum` or `upperBound` to double, a floating point division is performed, and results in 50.5.